# Binding binary field to ASP.NET DataGrid Causes Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, datagrid

I have a dataset with one of it's fields named `"Reviewed"`.

This dataset is popualted and below picture show it's data:
[image]

Now Im trying to show this dataset inside a DataGrid :

```
<ASP:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Reviewed" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderStyle-Wrap="True">
                                    <ItemStyle Wrap="false" HorizontalAlign="center" />
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <ASP:Checkbox  Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Reviewed") %>' runat="server" ID="Label22" />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <Asp:Checkbox id="Textbox5" width="40" Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Reviewed") %>' runat="server" />
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
        </ASP:TemplateColumn>
```

I get the following Error:

> *Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Cast from type
>   'DBNull' to type 'Boolean' is not valid.*

What I am doing wrong? Question is where DBNull comes from?

================================

Update:

Thanks for the nice answers. My main point of confusion was "STUPID" XML visualizer was wrongly showing Reviewed field as checked(as you see in the picture above). I checked the values in the dataset itself and realized all are indeed DBNUll.

Comment: as the error message says - you **can't convert dbNull to a boolean value**. you may have a look to this [blog](http://oudinia.blogspot.co.at/2008/01/aspnet-20-handling-null-values-for.html) which presents a solution to this or have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that some of your data coming from database is null. You need to check for that  before assigning.You might want to assign a default value Like.

```
iif((DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Reviewed") is DbNull.Value),false, DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Reviewed")))
```

You can also create a method that checks for both DBNULL and null values and returns you the appropriate value. like (it may have syntax error that you can correct)

```
<Asp:Checkbox id="Textbox5" width="40" Checked='<%# YourMethod(Eval("Reviewed")) %>' runat="server" />
```

Comment: See the picture I posted. All of data are populated.

Comment: Execute your query in the database and you will find out that some of the row is containing the null value which is causing error

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your markup code to this code.

```
<asp:Checkbox 
  Checked='<%# (Eval("reviewed")==DBNull.Value ? false : Eval("reviewed"))%>' 
  runat="server" ID="Label22" />
```

So instead of binding a nullValue to boolean property you *assign false if there is DBNull*. Credits go to [limno](http://forums.asp.net/t/1093197.aspx/1)

Comment: ah - noted it right now - but as @ehsan ullah provided a working example I will not adapt my example so others have a working example in c# too